# What is the maximum pixel width for images to be displayed without resizing?

Tags: support, design, images

What is the maximum pixel width an image in a post can have, to be displayed without getting resized on the *desktop version*?

Comment: Is there a reason that resizing is a problem? If you want the images next to each other, why not make them into a single image?

Comment: So ask what you want rather than what you're asking. There's likely padding between images that makes what you're asking less useful. You can also intentionally constrain the size of the image using size modifiers, which may be better as you can have them side by side but allow people to click on them for a higher quality image.

Comment: But, again, if fitting two images next to each other isn't an issue, why does it matter if the image is slightly resized? This seems like a non-issue?

Comment: @Catija I just want to know after which point I need to worry about resizing issues.

Comment: @AndrewT. the OP is talking about a desktop, not a phone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All images posted on SE are subject to the post's maximum width, which is <s>660 667</s> 659px.

[image: 660x100]

<sup>A single 660x100 image</sup>

[image: 330x100][image: 330x100]

<sup>Two 330x100 images without space/linebreak</sup>

Over 659px, then the image will get resized automatically to fit the post's width.

[image: 800x100]

<sup>A single 800x100 image</sup>

Comment: It seems the post's width is set to 66**7**px now...

Comment: And now it's 6**59**px, making the two 330px-wide images break :/

Comment: Probably to fix some minor bug somewhere. Bet it broke more than it fixed? ;-(