# Mobile font-size way too large

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, responsive-design

Just now, when reloading Stack Overflow on my mobile, the font sizes have been enlarged:

[image: screenshot of questions view on mobile]

---

I'm aware that the [mobile views are deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), but this change doesn't look intentional.

The font sizes increases from `17px` to `20.9231px` on question titles.

It's quite hard to see exactly how large the title gets compared to the other text; I'd recommend dragging your browser window to a mobile size to experience this yourself.
<sub>GIF: https://i.ibb.co/v3cZ8R1/Screen-Recording-2023-07-24-at-20-17-09.gif</sub>

---

The best comparison I've got is from my open tabs on my phone:

[image: comparison of before and after title sizes]

Asking here as this seems platform-wide.

Comment: Just had a look, and gotta say I agree, the font is noticeably larger than it was earlier today, and indeed far too large IMO. Although it only appears to be headers (question titles, "All Questions", "### questions", etc.) that it affects, normal text like usernames, question content are fine.

Comment: Yeah, the decreased density on the `/Questions` made me refresh a half dozen times thinking it was my phone because it seemed too flaky to be intentional. Hopefully a dumb CSS bug that can easily rolled back

Comment: Just FYI: There is, at this point, no such thing as "mobile view" for main and meta sites. It's all one page, which is "responsive", with "responsive" meaning that the same page will be (mostly) viewable using any screen width/viewport width from whatever minimum SE thinks is the minimum on which the page should be displayed (typically defined by the narrow widths of smartphones, but seems to be 320 pixels for SE) up to the maximum site width which SE thinks you should have your window set to, which is 1264 pixels when showing the left navigation and 1100 pixels without left navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the report @0stone0! This is due to a change in our design system Stacks that was shipped earlier today. I have a fix en route that should be live by end of day.

Comment: @DanCormier I'm not sure if you are the right person to ask but it has always irked me that the stack exchange home page does not have the same "responsiveness" as the other sites and seems rather "outdated" in terms of design. Is that intentional?

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken: I assume you mean https://stackexchange.com/? I believe it runs on an older/different version of the codebase compared to the regular Q&A sites, and has not been updated to be responsive. I don't think it's an intentional choice, just a matter of it not being touched in a while.

Comment: @V2Blast yes, is there reason as to why it has not been updated or is it just too old?Edit: I see, maybe it would be nice to update it if possible.

Comment: hah. Maybe its just dumb luck or caching, but super user still looks oversized and it had me confused this morning

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I don't think any other site besides SO and MSE have been fixed yet.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, That is true. I've read the tour page ang the upvote/downvote/accept buttons look outdated as well

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**tl;dr**: This bug has been [patched in our design system](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/commit/ebee94060f5eed2bc1950210565e6110a6dd3ef1) and the [update](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/releases/tag/v1.10.1) has been shipped to production.

---

Good catch @0stone0!

This was due to a change to some `font-size` values to replace explicit pixel values with calculated values based on custom properties. To be honest, I'm not sure why the calculated values cause this issue and explicit pixel values don't. Nevertheless, changing back to explicit pixel values resolves the issue.

**Note**: The cache on each network site needs to clear individually, so this may take a few days to be reflected.

Comment: Separate issue; have you altered the width? I know that I have formatted these 3 graphs in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44655723/ggplot2-heatmap-with-fixed-scale-colorbar-between-graphs/44656370#44656370) to fit in one row, which they don't anymore. I can simply change the width of each plot to be 215 to fix that, this is more of a question out of curiosity.

Comment: I don't believe so @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ. The changes (https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/1363/files) don't include alterations to any components that would impact the width of a post as far as I can tell.

Comment: Any progress on fixing any of the other font sizing / layout issues on mobile? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367616/222623 My first time chasing this post from 2 years ago but feels like an opportune time.

Comment: @DanCormier thanks. That's a quite old post, so maybe some changes were made at some point unrelated to the recent events (I just went to it to refresh my memory on perfect width to fit 3 images on one row si I can use it for my MSO post about this recent bug). Anyway, thanks again for the update and quick fix.

Comment: When will I see this be fixed? It's still broken on many main sites (SO, ELU, ELL, Movies&TV, Academia)

Comment: @Laurel Many network sites are requesting an outdated version of our compiled CSS without this fix. The cache may need to be purged to resolve this. I've made a request to an SRE for this, but it may be delayed until tomorrow. Sorry for the delay and thanks for being patient.

Comment: @DanCormier FYI, I believe the Math meta [Has mathstackexchange changed its font size?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35886) post is about this same issue.

Comment: I assume it’s a caching issue, but I’m still seeing this on RPG.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ there's [a change (reduce) in maximum post width](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305031/241919) sometime after 2017.

Comment: The font size is still huge on some of the SE sites. Even after cache purge. Eg. Cooking.SE.

Comment: @Roddy It's not (just) caching on your machine. The update has to travel through the CDN for each site. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Comment: It's still not fixed after 4 days. How much longer will it take to get it through the CDN?

Comment: I should perhaps specify that it is still not fixed on *Mathoverflow*. I see that it is fixed on other random sites of the network.

Comment: We are still experiencing this issue on [es.so]. Maybe wait a bit longer? Or it happens to be another issue?

Comment: CV and Maths still reeling...

Comment: Ask Ubuntu still has this issue on mobile as well...

Comment: @DanCormier what's going on since this still an issue on some sites?

Comment: After a week, [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) is still with this problem. Is it still a cache issue?

Comment: FWIW, CV and Maths are back to normal.

Comment: AU also fixed now - thanks.

Comment: I think we've finally hit the cache expiration on all sites  Thanks for being patient and please let me know if you find any sites that still have this issue after giving them a hard refresh.