# Are my images not centered?

Tags: support, images

I wanted to layout my images in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/323591/199241) centered, and I believe they are. Though I am using an ISP that seems to have banned imgur so I used a proxy to check them out, and a comment suggested that they aren't. Are they? Are they centered on the desktop and/or mobile?

Comment: You've used nonbreak spaces, and they would render differently on different devices, even different zooms. A better option is the `<center>` tag.

Comment: Ah, OK. It's much easier to do in sites with MathJax (with double dollar signs), I totally forgot center tag isn't allowed. I guess you should use `<pre>` then. More consistent than nbsp anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305080/are-my-images-not-centered#comment991719_305080), since you're manually adding non-breaking space characters, they will be rendered in different way on every browser/OS. Your images will be centered on some, and not centered on others.

To achieve better results, refer to the answers on [Is it possible to horizontally center an image on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites), basically saying to use `<pre></pre>` tag and put actual spaces.

I'm afraid there's no better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Any way I can use that w/o losing the `[![image][1]` format?

Comment: @Nae I'm afraid not.