# Why there is no command to center images?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images

Why there is no formatting command to center images in Stack Exchange posts?

Comment: Probably because Markdown itself doesn't support alignment. You can't center text either. I've tried to work around this with inline HTML, but either my HTML-fu is leaving me or it simply doesn't work fully on SE.

Comment: Why should there be one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why? It's not part of standard Markdown, and Stack Exchange only supports a limited set of HTML elements/attributes, to limit the complexity. New features have to be developed *and* maintained over time, so they chose to support only features they deemed essential. Centering images is apparently not one of them; note that in the official mobile apps, *all* images are centered automatically.

That said, there are some tricks to center images, e.g. using `<pre>` tags or `&nbsp;`; see [Is it possible to horizontally center an image on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25835/295232) for more details.